# Import-CSV not working correctly with German umlaute (ö / ä / ü)

Tags: powershell, csv

I am adding one column to csv files in a Folder. It works fine, but the source file has the German umlaute (ä, ö, ü) in the fields.

The Destination file only a question mark surrounded by a black square. How can I solve this with a single Script doing this for all Files in my Folder?

```
$Folder="Y:\EMA 2017\tarif counts" 

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter *.csv -Recurse | 


ForEach-Object { 

  $Col = $_.Basename

  Import-Csv $_.Fullname -delimiter ';' |

  Select-Object *,@{Name='Monat';Expression={$Col}} | 

  Export-Csv ($_.DirectoryName + '\New_' + $_.Name) -delimiter ';'
-NoType -Encoding UTF8

}
```

Comment: Might be relevant? [Exporting German umlauts with PowerShell 3 by Out-File CMDlet](//stackoverflow.com/q/38842789)

Comment: I think that your script is correct but your trouble is at a file systems level. I guess that `Y:\EMA 2017\tarif counts` is a remote share (with a different file system?). For troubleshooting I would start to reveal the actual basename (`write-host $col`) and with that try to exclude all the `CSV` imports and - exports. Or copy (some) of the files to your local drive and check from there.

Comment: already did it from local drive and the problem still persists. File System is a Remote Share but it is the same as on the Local Machine - Both Windows - NTFS - I think the Problem is located in the import routine. Maybe i have to declarate charset to windows current instead of utf8?